# require('node-fetch') gives ERR_REQUIRE_ESM

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I just use

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch')
```

And I get

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rollbot\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js from C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rollbot\index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rollbot\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js in C:\Users\Alex\Desktop\rollbot\index.js to a 
dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
{
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

All my other packages work, just node-fetch does this. What should I do in order to use node-fetch?

Answer (score 67, accepted):

From the `node-fetch` [package readme](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch#installation):

> node-fetch is an ESM-only module - you are not able to import it with
> require. We recommend you stay on v2 which is built with CommonJS
> unless you use ESM yourself. We will continue to publish critical bug
> fixes for it.

If you want to `require` it, then downgrade to v2.

The other option you have is to use async `import('node-fetch').then(...)`

Comment: Or better use Axios, really a lot of confusion because of ES, CommonJs, and also typescript configs.

Comment: Install the second version: npm install node-fetch@2

Comment: With yarn it should be `yarn add node-fetch@2`.

Answer (score 113):

What I found is that the latest version of `node-fetch` changed to ES modules by default. You can:

1. Uninstall the current version of node-fetch with `npm uninstall node-fetch`
2. Install the second version: `npm install node-fetch@2`

It has worked for me!

Comment: god bless you and blessed be the womb that brought you forth.

Comment: Thank you so much, I was getting error for octokit and your solution is fixed it.

Comment: the version 2 just did

Answer (score 42):

**LATEST UPDATE MAY 2022**

**You may not needed `node-fetch` anymore.**

In the latest version of `Node.js` ([18.0.0](https://github.com/nodejs/node/blob/master/doc/changelogs/CHANGELOG_V18.md#18.1.0)), global fetch (experimental) is enabled by default.

```
const res = await fetch('https://nodejs.org/api/documentation.json');
if (res.ok) {
  const data = await res.json();
  console.log(data);
}
```

Through this addition, the following globals are made available: `fetch, FormData, Headers, Request, Response`.

> You may disable this API with the `--no-experimental-fetch`
> command-line flag.

Answer (score 26):

In my case, I personally found it easier to require ('cross-fetch') instead. The documentation is here: [cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch)

It can be used in CommonJS as well as ES6 modules.

Comment: Your answer could be improved with additional supporting information. Please [edit] to add further details, such as citations or documentation, so that others can confirm that your answer is correct. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).

Comment: I was trying to use node-fetch with typescript and using cross-fetch worked without any hiccups.

Comment: This is the answer. I wasted too much time with trying to make `node-fetch` work (v2 doesn't have typescript types, v3 work only in ESM which is not well suported in TS in node.js yet, ugh...). `cross-fetch` just works.

Comment: [Read the docs](https://github.com/lquixada/cross-fetch#how-does-cross-fetch-work): _How does cross-fetch work?_ (...) _If you're in node, it delivers you the node-fetch library_. It uses node-fetch v2, so you should just downgrade node-fetch instead of adding another unnecessary dependency layer.

Comment: cross-fetch works only over httpS

Answer (score 8):

You can use `node-fetch@3` from CommonJS using dynamic imports. Since fetch is already an async API you can define a wrapper like this:

fetch.js

```js
exports.fetch = async function (url, init) {
    const {default: fetch} = await import("node-fetch");
    return await fetch(url, init);
};
```

You can then use the wrapper like this:

```js
const fetch = require("./fetch");
```

This trick doesn't work out of the box in TypeScript since TypeScript transforms the dynamic import to a regular require. To work around this just add the plain `fetch.js` to your project and also add a type declaration:

fetch.d.ts

```
/**
 * @param { import("node-fetch").RequestInfo} url
 * @param {import("node-fetch").RequestInit} init
 * @returns {Promise<import("node-fetch").Response>}
 */
export function fetch(
    url: import("node-fetch").RequestInfo,
    init: import("node-fetch").RequestInit
): Promise<import("node-fetch").Response>;
```

[cross-fetch](https://www.npmjs.com/package/cross-fetch) is a nice alternative but it's wrapping a 2.x version of `node-fetch` so you won't get the latest version.

Answer (score 4):

NodeJS supports two different module types:

- the original CommonJS module that uses `require()` to load other modules
- the newer ECMAScript modules (aka ESM) that use `import` to load other modules.

As mentioned in `node-fetch` [changelog](https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/HEAD/docs/v3-UPGRADE-GUIDE.md#converted-to-es-module) (28 Aug 2021):

> This module was converted to be a ESM only package in version `3.0.0-beta.10`. `node-fetch` is an ESM-only module — you are not able to import it with `require`. We recommend you stay on `v2` which is built with CommonJS unless you use ESM yourself. We will continue to publish critical bug fixes for it.
>
> Alternatively, you can use the async `import()` function from CommonJS to load `node-fetch` asynchronously:
>
> ```js
> const fetch = (...args) => import('node-fetch').then(({default: fetch}) => fetch(...args));
> ```

So, you can use this one-liner instead of `const fetch = require('node-fetch')`.

Or instead of trying to load `node-fetch`, you can install and load the module [`node-fetch-commonjs`](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch-commonjs) instead. It's a CommonJS wrapper around `node-fetch` that should provide you compatibility:

```js
const fetch = require('node-fetch-commonjs')
```

Answer (score 0):

https://github.com/alex-kinokon/esm-hook worked nicely for me. Require it before you try to import node-fetch. Either via --require or at the top of your script.