# ERROR_REQUIRE_ESM in discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I have a code which I'm doing on replit, and I'm pretty new to node.js so I really do need assistance with this. I have a code which is this:

```py
const Discord = require("discord.js")
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
const client = new Discord.Client()
const mySecret = process.env['TOKEN']

function getQuote() {
    return fetch('https://zenquotes.io/api/random')
     .then(res => {
         return res.json
     })
     .then(data => {
         return data[0]["q"] + " —" +  data [0]["a"]
     })



}

client.on("ready", () => {
    console.log('Logged in as ${client.user.tag}' )
})

client.on("message", msg => {
    if (msg.author.bot) return



    if (msg.content === "$inspire") {
        getQuote().then(quote => msg.channel.send(quote))

    }
})


client.login(process.env.TOKEN)
```

However, I'm receiving the error:

```py
npx node .
/home/runner/1Starty/index.js:2
const fetch = require("node-fetch")
              ^

Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module /home/runner/1Starty/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js from /home/runner/1Starty/index.js not supported.
Instead change the require of /home/runner/1Starty/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js in /home/runner/1Starty/index.js to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
    at Object.<anonymous> (/home/runner/1Starty/index.js:2:15) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

May someone help me on why this is the case?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [require('node-fetch') gives ERR\_REQUIRE\_ESM](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69087292/requirenode-fetch-gives-err-require-esm)

Answer (score 1):

Open shell and run this command

```sh
npm i node-fetch@2.6.6
```

Comment: One liner answers are not recommended, try explaining how the solution will help with the problem and convert line into steps.