# Node package 'node-fetch' SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier

Tags: node.js, npm

I have a problem. I am trying to run my NodeJS script using the command:

```
node /var/script/NodeJS/test.js
```

But when I run it, I get the following error:

```
/var/script/NodeJS/node_modules/node-fetch/src/index.js:9
import http from 'http';
       ^^^^

SyntaxError: Unexpected identifier
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:723:23)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
    at Module.load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:653:32)
    at tryModuleLoad (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:593:12)
    at Function.Module._load (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:585:3)
    at Module.require (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:692:17)
    at require (internal/modules/cjs/helpers.js:25:18)
    at Object.<anonymous> (/var/script/NodeJS/test.js:2:15)
    at Module._compile (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:778:30)
    at Object.Module._extensions..js (internal/modules/cjs/loader.js:789:10)
```

I have already run the following commands in the terminal:

```
cd /var/script/NodeJS
npm install
npm install http
npm install node-fetch
```

I am running node version: `v10.19.0`

Here is the code I have that gives the error:

```
const express = require("express");
const fetch = require('node-fetch');
const app = express();
const PORT = process.env.PORT = 8787;
let router = express.Router();
```

It's just the imports, but this code already gives the provided error!
I can see both the modules in the `node_module` folder, so why am I getting this error and how can I fix this?

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/62554884/5781499

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: require() of ES modules is not supported when importing node-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

rename file extension from `.js` to `.mjs`

filename must be: `test.mjs`

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';

const express = require("express");

const app = express();
let router = express.Router();


const PORT = process.env.PORT = 8787;
```

also keep in mind node-fetch has requriements on node version:

https://github.com/node-fetch/node-fetch/blob/main/package.json#L14

```
  "engines": {
    "node": "^12.20.0 || ^14.13.1 || >=16.0.0"
  },
```

run it as: `node test.mjs`

[image: mjs support test]

---

**Bonus**: If You don't like to use mjs and etc try to install [node-fetch@2.6.5](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch/v/2.6.5)

```
npm i --save node-fetch@2.6.5
```

Comment: That gives me the same error?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk better to put Your code and node version

Comment: Sorry, I have added it

Comment: Your latest edit still gives me the error, should I upgrade node to the latest version?

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk see node-fetch is supported on 12.20+, 14.13.1+, 16=+  make sure You've errors on version which supposed to work

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk I've added screenshot where same code in `test.js` and `test.mjs` so depending on extension it works differently.

Comment: @A.Vreeswijk another way is to install old version: `npm i --save node-fetch@2.6.5`  but first remove `3.x.x` : `npm uninstall --save node-fetch`

Answer (score 4):

This can happen if you use a 3.X version of node-fetch and a Node version less than 12.20.0

> Because node-fetch from v3 is an ESM-only module.

According to the [documents](https://www.npmjs.com/package/node-fetch#loading-and-configuring-the-module) you must install a version 2.X or less

```
npm install node-fetch@2
```