# "require" not supported even though I'm using "import"

Tags: javascript, typescript, fetch

Code:

```
import fetch from 'node-fetch';
```

Error:

```
Error [ERR_REQUIRE_ESM]: require() of ES Module C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\Documents\Work\Typescript\CoredV5-TS\node_modules\node-fetch\src\index.js from C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\Documents\Work\Typescript\CoredV5-TS\src\commands\general\ping.ts not supported.
Instead change the require of index.js in C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\Documents\Work\Typescript\CoredV5-TS\src\commands\general\ping.ts to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.    
    at Object.<anonymous> (C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\Documents\Work\Typescript\CoredV5-TS\src\commands\general\ping.ts:15:38)
    at Module.m._compile (C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:704:29)
    at Object.require.extensions.<computed> [as .ts] (C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\AppData\Local\Yarn\Data\global\node_modules\ts-node\dist\index.js:706:16)
    at bot.<anonymous> (C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\Documents\Work\Typescript\CoredV5-TS\src\classes\bot.ts:43:44)
    at Generator.next (<anonymous>)
    at fulfilled (C:\Users\youar_mnnijcy\Documents\Work\Typescript\CoredV5-TS\src\classes\bot.ts:5:58) {
  code: 'ERR_REQUIRE_ESM'
}
```

Additional Information:

`"node-fetch": "^3.0.0"`

`"@types/node-fetch": "^3.0.3"`

When I tried downgrading to v2.6.2, I got an error from my IDE to install `@types/node-fetch`, which I installed, but I still get that error.

Comment: is the code sample taken from `CoredV5-TS\src\commands\general\ping.ts`?

Comment: @thchp yes! it is from ping

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Error: require() of ES modules is not supported when importing node-fetch](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch)

Comment: @thchp no it doesn't, my file is a typescript file, not a typescript file. So I don't know why this is happening

Comment: please provide your .tsconfig file

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**How I fixed this problem:**

Uninstall node-fetch and the types,

`npm uninstall node-fetch`
`npm uninstall @types/node-fetch`

Install any **2.** version of `node-fetch`, I used `node-fetch@^2.6.1` with `@types/node-fetch@2.5.12`

**Installation:**

`npm install node-fetch@^2.6.1`
`npm install --save-dev @types/node-fetch@2.5.12`

**Why?**

Because Chalk has switched to ESM so projects that do not support it must use version 4. [Read Here](https://github.com/chalk/chalk/releases/tag/v5.0.0) for more information.

Comment: this is the first working answer after researching a bunch of StackOverflow answers. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

By default, TypeScript will compile your code into `ES3` JavaScript. This will cause your import to be compiled into [this](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/modules.html#commonjs--node-simplemodulejs). You can change that behavior by switching the [target](https://www.typescriptlang.org/tsconfig#target) in your `tsconfig` to `ES6` or `ES2015`.

This way the generated JavaScript will use `import` instead of `require` and work with `node-fetch@3.x`

Comment: It already is "ES6".