# Module import or export statement unexpected here Javascript

Tags: javascript, node.js, node-fetch

I am trying to use node fetch to retrieve a string from a Misty robot and then pass this information to a Lobe ML model for a senior year developmental class.
The problem is that fetch was originally not defined. I then installed the package in the terminal and am now stuck at "Module import or export statement unexpected here" when I try to import the package in my file. I am super confused on how to solve this and have spent the last 3 class periods reading docs and other stack overflow posts and can not find anything that works for me. Does anyone have any tips?

Comment: Can you post your code and the package.json file content?

Comment: Are you able to identify the module that fails the import? Please link the npm package as well as how you are importing the module.

Comment: package.json: {
  "name": "pkg",
  "version": "1.0.0",
  "description": "",
  "main": "MaskDetection.js",
  "scripts": {
    "test": "echo \"Error: no test specified\" && exit 1"
  },
  "author": "",
  "license": "ISC",
  "dependencies": {
    "node-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "uniq": "^1.0.1"
  }
}

Comment: import fetch from "node-fetch";

Promise.race([
 fetch('http://10.1.100.216/api/cameras/rgb?base64=true&fileName=lol&width=1920&height=1080&displayOnScreen=false&overwriteExisting=true', {
  method: 'GET'
 }),
 new Promise((_, reject) => setTimeout(() => reject(new Error('timeout')), 10000))
])

Comment: @dan wdym by link the npm package?

Comment: @excitedrasin Seeing how it's imported might help with debugging it. You can move some of the additional info to your question via edit.
The import looks correct. I am assuming if you comment out the import the error is gone?  If you are importing it into a browser environment then it may fail if it's not a node environment. If you can provide more complete demo that can be replicated it would help a lot.

Comment: @excitedrasin You may also want to check if the `import` syntax is working for you by creating a small `.js` file to test this. This question and their answer may be relevant to your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch