# Ionic 7 viewer and pdf generator plugin

Tags: ionic-framework, printing, pdf-generation, ionic7

Which plugin to install to preview and download the PDF, and use with ionic 7, I tried cordova-plugin-printer and it is giving conflicts with the dependencies version, which one to use with ionic 7?

I installed cordova-plugin-printer --force, and npm install @awesome-cordova-plugins/printer --force, but when running the ionic cap sync command, the following error appeared:

An unhandled exception occurred: require() of ES Module C:\Users\kaio_\OneDrive\Desktop\testAppCLone\MyCV\MyCV\node_modules@angular\compiler\fesm2022\compiler.mjs not supported.
Instead change the require of C:\Users\kaio_\OneDrive\Área de Trabalho\testAppCLone\MyCV\MyCV\node_modules@angular\compiler\fesm2022\compiler.mjs to a dynamic import() which is available in all CommonJS modules.
See "D:\Temp01\ng-rYoHQy\angular-errors.log" for further details.
[ERROR] An error occurred while running subprocess ng.

```
    ng.cmd run app:build exited with exit code 127.

    Re-running this command with the --verbose flag may provide more information.
```

Comment: Maybe here is the answer, I got `ERR_REQUIRE_ESM` error alongside it: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/69041454/error-require-of-es-modules-is-not-supported-when-importing-node-fetch